# how to retrieve selected fields from collection in mongodb in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

Below is the code where I am getting the all fields of the collection “SiteInfo”, My requirement is to retrieve specific set of fields from the collection, that is Sitename, SiteAddress, SiteLocation, we don’t want all fields instead only 3 specific fields

How to add this in the below code? i have many functions related to different tables and all have the same code structure

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("V1/SInfo")]
public IHttpActionResult getANPRSiteInfo()
{
    try
    {
        
        string json = "";
        IMongoDatabase db = dbClient.GetDatabase(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProdDB"]);
        var Pool = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteInfo"]);                              
        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Status", true);
        var documents = Pool.Find(filter).ToList();
        
        foreach (var doc in documents)
        {
            sb.Append(doc.ToString());
        }
         return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sb.Replace("\"", "").ToString()));
       
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use 'Projection' here is a short [article](https://digitteck.com/mongo-csharp/projections_in_mongo_csharp/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept in mongodb called *projection* it allows to return particular fields of a document from a query. Here are the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

Here is the example usage for C# mongodb driver:

```cs
// here is your filter
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Status", true);
// create a projection definition with fields that you want to include 
var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection
    .Include("SiteName") // include fields that you want to be in the output
    .Include("SiteAddress")
    .Include("SiteLocation")
    .Exclude("_id"); // this is an example of exclusion, _id is usually included by default

 var documents = Pool.Find(filter).Project<BsonDocument>(projection).ToList();
```